# How to disable touch row in uitable without disable highlight

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

In UITable i get index of selected row. And when i get index of row i want disable her that then it can not be pressed but highlight should remain. And when i click another row it is highlight and previous row is enable and highlight is disable.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CellIndex = indexPath.row;
    [self.containerViewController swapViewControllers:CellIndex];
}
```

[image]

I want nothing happens if you click on the row that is already pressed.
Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a variable that knows which was the last row pressed, and check in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(previouslySelectedIndexPath == indexPath)
        return;
    previouslySelectedIndexPath = indexPath;

    CellIndex = indexPath.row;
    [self.containerViewController swapViewControllers:CellIndex];
}
```